# What does Obsoleting Packages mean in output of yum check-update?

Tags: rhel, yum, upgrade, version

The output of "yum -q check-update" is following:
[image]

It shows the available version for grub2-tools is 2.02-142.e18 (in dark green color)

The obsoleting packages shows following update versions of grub2-tool:

2.02-123.e18_6.8 (in fainted green color)

2.02-142.e18 (in fainted green color)

2.02-123.e18 (in fainted red color)

The installed version of grub2-toool is 2.02-142.e18:
[image]

Similarly with the other packages (grub2-common, grub2-pc, etc.) in the output of "yum -q check-update".

I want to understand about the details under the Obsoleting Packages. What do the details under the Obsoleting Packages signify?

Comment: Wherever possible copy-paste text instead of posting screenshots. You can use Markdown to make the output distinct from the rest of the text.

Comment: Thanks @Krackout. But in this case, I wanted to share the color of the text too so it was important to add screenshots.